# history.back and RadEditor clears other form data

Tags: telerik, browser-history

I have a strange scenario :

I am using asp.net mvc and I have a form which has a combination of HTML input fields and [Telerik RadEditor](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx).

When validation fails on my form I have *history.back* to get the user back to the form. If RadEditor has some text and if validation fails then I am losing all the data in the fields that are right below the RadEditor control. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

IS the problem reproducible without RadEditor on the page? 
Have you tried to set the ContentAreaMode property of RadEditor to DIV and test?